# html 5 datalist value

Tags: html, forms

how can I get the "id" instead of "name" when i submit the form.

```
<input type="text" list='name' name='test1'/>
                <datalist id="test1">
                    <?php
                        if(!empty($data)){
                            foreach($data as $flag){
                                echo "<option label ='".$flag['id']."' >".$flag['name']."</option>";
                            }
                        }else{
                            echo "<option> empty </option>";
                        }
                    ?>
                </datalist>
```

I have tried using value = $flag['id'], but I still get "name" when i submit it.

Comment: The `id` is not sent to the server. Only the `name` and `value`.

Answer (score 0):

The `id` is not sent to the server with a regular submitting of a form. Only the `name`- and `value` attributes are.

If you really wanted to get the `id`s too, you could have a hidden `<input>` element with an array for value, containing all the relevant `id`s you want.

Here's an example:

HTML

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="inp1" />
    <input type="text" name="surname" id="inp2" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ids[]" value="inp1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ids[]" value="inp2" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

PHP

```
foreach($_POST['ids'] as $id)
{
    echo '<option label="' . $id . '">' . array_search($id, $_POST) . '</option>';
}
```